# What is task status PA refers to?

Tags: linux, process, rhel7, crash

I am looking into a crash dump for RHEL 7.4. It shows some of the task status as PA. 
[image]

None of the help pages talk about the details of this task status.

1. can anyone tell me what PA refers as the status of task?
2. any link or details about all the process status mentioned in crash utility?
   [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PArked. You may have some offline CPUs given that state, but have someone who really understands the scheduler have a look at it.

These corresponds to the [process state characters from /proc/[pid]/stat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html):

```
                    R  Running
                    S  Sleeping in an interruptible wait
                    D  Waiting in uninterruptible disk sleep
                    Z  Zombie
                    T  Stopped (on a signal) or (before Linux 2.6.33) trace stopped
                    t  Tracing stop (Linux 2.6.33 onward)
                    W  Paging (only before Linux 2.6.0)
                    X  Dead (from Linux 2.6.0 onward)
                    x  Dead (Linux 2.6.33 to 3.13 only)
                    K  Wakekill (Linux 2.6.33 to 3.13 only)
                    W  Waking (Linux 2.6.33 to 3.13 only)
                    P  Parked (Linux 3.9 to 3.13 only)
```

Note that crash does [its own interpretation of the state constants in task.c](https://github.com/crash-utility/crash/blob/c0371f6ee2cae31ec9f506bbd231ab8fbe334c13/task.c#L5513). For example, UNinterruptible when proc reports Disk. The former is perhaps more technically correct, but practically most uninterruptable tasks are doing I/O.